# Causality on an accumulator system

Tags: signal-processing, digital-communications, math

Can anybody explain why is this system not causal.

$$T[x[n]] = \sum_{k=n_0}^{n} x[k]]$$

How does it depend from future inputs when $$n < n_0$$.

From what i've searched if \$n_0\$ was \$-\infty\$ it would be causal. But since \$n_0\$ can be anything and summation when \$n < n_0\$ is possible resulting in zero, I don't know if this is the reason.

Comment: When \$n\$ is **less than** \$n0\$?  That means that \$n0\$ is a future time.

Comment: And do you mean \$n0\$ (`\$n0\$`), or \$n_0\$ (`\$n_0\$`)?

Comment: I wanted to type \$n_0\$

Comment: When \$n\$ is less than \$n_0\$. I guess that is the part that I dont get, I realize it now. How does it express a future input?

Answer (score 0):

if n0 is greater than n then the system will depend on a future input, which means it is not causal.

For example, lets say \$n\$ = 3 and \$n0\$ = 5, which satisfies \$n\$ < \$n0\$

Then \$T\$[\$x[3]]\$ = \$x[3]\$ + \$x[4]\$ + \$x[5]\$

the current sample is \$n\$=3 but the sum includes the future samples of \$n\$=4 and \$n\$=5

Comment: Isnt the summation zero when \$n_0\$ is bigger than \$n\$ ?. wiki(special case): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Special_cases

Comment: From what i've searched if $n_0$ was $-\infty$ it would be causal. But since $n_0$ can be anything and summation when $n < n_0$ is possible resulting in zero, I don't know.